# Image clarity is losses after executing some codes in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, brightness, clarity

Anybody have an idea about [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package in flutter??
I have some code to customise the image file..

```
      img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(await file!.readAsBytes());
      img.Image? brightenedImage = img.adjustColor(image!, brightness: 1 + _brightnessValue);
      final Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
      File('$documentPath/example.jpeg').writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(image));
      final File receiptFile = File('$documentPath/example.jpeg');
```

After applying this code, the image clarity is losses.
Anyone have an idea please reply...